# Primitives missing from properties copied by Object.assign in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, assign

I have a question about `Object.assign()`.

```js
const v1 = 'abc';
const v2 = true;
const v3 = 10;
const v4 = Symbol('foo');

//Primitives will be wrapped to objects
const obj = Object.assign({}, v1, null, v2, undefined, v3, v4); 
// Primitives will be wrapped, null and undefined will be ignored.
// Note, only string wrappers can have own enumerable properties.
console.log(obj); // { "0": "a", "1": "b", "2": "c" }
```

The output is just `{ "0": "a", "1": "b", "2": "c" }`. I guess this is the result of `"abc"` being wrapped to an object.

Comment says `null` and `undefined` are ignored so they are not in the output.

But what of `v2`, `v3`, and `v4`? They are not present in the output so I wonder what they become if wrapped to objects.

Can you explain why only `{ "0": "a", "1": "b", "2": "c" }` is in the output? I'm guessing this is because wrappers of `true` and `10` and `Symbol('foo')` have no own enumerable properties. Am I on the right track?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct. Strings have enumerable properties while booleans, numbers, and symbols do not. According to [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> The Object.assign() method only copies enumerable and own properties from a source object to a target object.

Answer (score 1):

> But what of v2, v3, and v4? They are not present in the output so I wonder what they become if wrapped to objects.

Instances of their respective type, `Boolean`, `Number` and `Symbol`.

Only these types have no enumerable properties that could be assigned, only inherited methods.

Check this out:

```js
var obj = {};
obj.test = 1;
Object.defineProperty(obj, "foo", {
  enumerable: false,
  value: 13
});

console.log("obj.foo", obj.foo);
console.log("assigned", Object.assign({}, obj)); // foo is not enumerable

var obj2 = Object.create({ bar: 42 });
obj2.test = 2;
console.log("obj2.bar", obj2.bar);
console.log("assigned", Object.assign({}, obj2)); // bar is inherited, not own
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example based on Thomas' snippet.

```js
//propertyIsEnumerable()

var obj = {};
obj.test = 1;
Object.defineProperty(obj, "foo", {
  enumerable: false,
  value: 13
});

console.log(obj.propertyIsEnumerable('foo'));
//console.log("obj.foo", obj.foo);
//console.log("assigned", Object.assign({}, obj)); // foo is not enumerable

var obj2 = Object.create({ bar: 42 });
obj2.test = 2;
//console.log("obj2.bar", obj2.bar);
//console.log("assigned", Object.assign({}, obj2)); // bar is inherited, not own

console.log(obj2.propertyIsEnumerable('bar'));
```

As you can see both property 'foo' and 'bar' are not enumerable so they both output `false`.

As Thomas mentioned, 'foo' is not enumerable simply because descriptor defines it as `enumerable: false`, and 'bar' is not own property of obj2 but inherited so it is also not enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign() copies the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. For example:

```js
const sourceObject = {
    v1: 'abc',
    v2: true,
    v3: 10
};

const sourceObject2 = {
    b1: 'def',
    b2: false
};

const obj = Object.assign(sourceObject, sourceObject2); 
console.log(obj);
```